# How do I add a new NoteProperty to the Format-Table view?

Tags: powershell

I'm playing with `Get-NetTCPConnection` as a replacement for `netstat` and I'm trying to come up with a solution for the `-b` flag.

> -b    Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port.

So far, I have `Add-Member` like so

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | %{ Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyMembers @{OwningProcessName=(Get-Process -PID $_.OwningProcess).Name} -PassThru }
```

Which seems to add the NoteProperty to the object.

```
PS> Get-NetTCPConnection | %{ Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyMembers @{OwningProcessName=(Get-Process -PID $_.OwningProcess).Name} -PassThru } | Get-Member -Name OwningProcessName


   TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetTCPConnection

Name              MemberType   Definition
----              ----------   ----------
OwningProcessName NoteProperty string OwningProcessName=msedge
```

But, I can't seem to get that column to show up in `Format-Table` along with all of the default properties. Ideally, I'd like to append it without repeating the entire list of default properties.

I ran this command in a maximized window:

```
PS> Get-NetTCPConnection | %{ Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyMembers @{OwningProcessName=(Get-Process -PID $_.OwningProcess).Name} -PassThru } | Format-Table -AutoSize

LocalAddress    LocalPort RemoteAddress   RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------    --------- -------------   ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
::1             50737     ::              0          Listen                     12676
::              49674     ::              0          Listen                     1180
::              49671     ::              0          Listen                     1212
```

Answer (score 2):

In [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6) it says that *"The object type determines the default layout and properties that are displayed in each column, but you can use the Property parameter to select the properties that you want to see."*

This means you need to either need to use the `-Property` parameter and list the properties you wish to see

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Foreach-Object { 
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{OwningProcessName=($_.OwningProcess).Name} -PassThru |
} | 
Format-Table -Property LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State, AppliedSetting, OwningProcess, OwningProcessName -AutoSize
```

Or output new objects that contain only the properties you need and that have the new property added:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Foreach-Object { 
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{OwningProcessName=($_.OwningProcess).Name} -PassThru |
    Select-Object LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State, AppliedSetting, OwningProcess, OwningProcessName
} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Changing the default properties the `Format-Table` cmdlet displays is perhaps possible by editing the `C:\windows\systems32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Types.ps1xml`, but I don't think this is advisable and of course at your own risk.
I found blogs about that [here](https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-changing-a-command-outputs-default-formatting) and also [here](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/) in case you are interested.